# Excel VBA keeps inputting at signs before my sheet name in formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I'm pretty new to VBA so bear with me. I am running a piece of code that duplicates a worksheet and then replaces the old sheet names in the formulas to the new sheet names in the new workbook. For some reason it works perfectly fine for the entire selection except for 3 cells C37:E37 where it's inserting and @ sign in front of the sheet names within the sumproduct section of the formula. All the other formulas are pretty basic just adding things from other sheets so no sumproduct/if statements.

**Code:**

```
 Windows("CFD_AOPSep2023.xlsm").Activate
        Sheet2.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Workbooks("NewWB.xlsx").Sheets(1)
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:Q38").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="[CFD_AOPSep2023.xlsm]STEP 1 Current Items", Replacement:="STEP 1 Current Items", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:Q38").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="[CFD_AOPSep2023.xlsm]STEP 2 New SOW", Replacement:="STEP 2 New SOW", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:Q38").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="[CFD_AOPSep2023.xlsm]STEP 3 Non-Inventory Charges", Replacement:="STEP 3 Non-Inventory Charges", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("A1:Q38").Select
        Selection.Replace What:="[CFD_AOPSep2023.xlsm]STEP 4 Inactive Items", Replacement:="STEP 4 Inactive Items", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I have tried replacing just the @ sign section in the formula but the @ sign still remains. I've also tried inserting hardcoded formula's into those three cells after the find and replace and that didn't work either.

Tried the two below things to try and fix and they didn't work.

```
Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C37:E37").Select
Selection.Replace What:="@", Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

```
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C37").Select
        Selection.Formula = "=(((('STEP 1 Current Items'!S11-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$17:$I$1048576='STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$19,1,0),'STEP 1 Current Items'!S$17:S$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 1 Current Items'!$E$17:$E$1048576,-2,)))/'STEP 1 Current Items'!S11)*'STEP 1 Current Items'!S11)+(IFERROR(('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!S9-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$14:$I$1048576='STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$15,1,0),'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!S$14:S$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$E$14:$E$1048576,0,)))/'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!S9,0)*'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!S9)+('STEP 3 Non-Inventory Charges'!N11*$L$32))/C35"
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("D37").Select
        Selection.Formula = "=(((('STEP 1 Current Items'!T11-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$17:$I$1048576='STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$19,1,0),'STEP 1 Current Items'!T$17:T$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 1 Current Items'!$E$17:$E$1048576,-2,)))/'STEP 1 Current Items'!T11)*'STEP 1 Current Items'!T11)+(IFERROR(('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!T9-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$14:$I$1048576='STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$15,1,0),'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!T$14:T$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$E$14:$E$1048576,0,)))/'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!T9,0)*'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!T9)+('STEP 3 Non-Inventory Charges'!O11*$L$32))/D35"
        
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("E37").Select
        Selection.Formula = "=(((('STEP 1 Current Items'!U11-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$17:$I$1048576='STEP 1 Current Items'!$I$19,1,0),'STEP 1 Current Items'!U$17:U$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 1 Current Items'!$E$17:$E$1048576,-2,)))/'STEP 1 Current Items'!U11)*'STEP 1 Current Items'!U11)+(IFERROR(('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!U9-SUMPRODUCT(IF('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$14:$I$1048576='STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$I$15,1,0),'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!U$14:U$1048576,OFFSET('STEP 4 Inactive Items'!$E$14:$E$1048576,0,)))/'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!U9,0)*'STEP 4 Inactive Items'!U9)+('STEP 3 Non-Inventory Charges'!P11*$L$32))/E35"
```

Comment: You'd need to use Formula2 not Formula. Those will be very inefficient formulas though due to the very large ranges and use of `OFFSET`

Comment: Background to the `@` - https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34